# Wrong results when using two annotate expressions concurrently

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, orm

Assume the following tables:

```
class Table1(models.Model): 
    Column1 = models.IntegerField()
class Table2(models.Model):  
    Column2 = models.IntegerField()
class Table3(models.Model):  
    Table1 = models.ForeignKey(Table1, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Table2 = models.ForeignKey(Table2, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Column3 = models.IntegerField()
class Table4(models.Model):  
    Table1 = models.ForeignKey(Table1, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Table3 = models.ForeignKey(Table3, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Column4 = models.IntegerField()
```

This annotate expression returns right answer:

```
print(Table1.objects.annotate(Exp1=Sum(
            Case(
                When(table3__Table2__Column2__in=[2, 3],
                     then=F('table3__Column3')),
                default=Value(0)
            ),
    )).values('Exp1'))
```

That is:

```
<QuerySet [{'Exp1': 96}]>
```

And I need to define another annotate expression as below:

```
print(Table1.objects.annotate(Exp2=Sum(
            Case(
                When(table4__Table3__Table2__Column2=3,
                     then=F('table4__Column4')),
                default=Value(0)
            ),
      )).values('Exp2'))
```

Again the result is correct:

```
<QuerySet [{'Exp2': 0}]>
```

Finally, I want to combine these two in one command:

```
print(Table1.objects.annotate(Exp1=Sum(
            Case(
                When(table3__Table2__Column2__in=[2, 3],
                     then=F('table3__Column3')),
                default=Value(0)
            ),
    ), Exp2=Sum(
            Case(
                When(table4__Table3__Table2__Column2=3,
                     then=F('table4__Column4')),
                default=Value(0)
            ),
    )).values('Exp1', 'Exp2'))
```

But unfortunately the result is not correct:

```
<QuerySet [{'Exp2': 0, 'Exp1': 480}]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is reported [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060) but it's not solved yet even in Django 1.11. The issue is related to joining two tables in reverse relations.
Notice that distinct parameter works well for Count but not for Sum. So I used a trick and wrote the below ORM that works pretty well:

```
print(Table1.objects.annotate(
    temp_Exp1=Sum(
            Case(
                When(table3__Table2__Column2__in=[2, 3],
                     then=F('table3__Column3')),
                default=Value(0)
            ),), 
    temp_Exp2=Sum(
            Case(
                When(table4__Table3__Table2__Column2=3,
                     then=F('table4__Column4')),
                default=Value(0)
            ),),
    table3_count=Count('table3'),
    table3_count_distinct=Count('table3', distinct=True),
    table4_count=Count('table4'),
    table4_count_distinct=Count('table4', distinct=True),
).annotate(
    Exp1=F('temp_Exp1')*F('table3_count_distinct')/F('table3_count'),
    Exp2=F('temp_Exp2')*F('table4_count_distinct')/F('table4_count'),
).values('Exp1', 'Exp2'))
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a caveat when using multiple aggregations with `annotate`:

> Combining multiple aggregations with `annotate()` will yield the wrong
>   results because joins are used instead of subqueries.
>   For most aggregates, there is no way to avoid this problem...

And unlike aggregation with `Count`, `Sum` does not take a `distinct` parameter that could help dedupe items. I guess you should keep the distinct queries if you are to have correct results.

See [Combining multiple aggregations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations).

Comment: I added distinct=True before closing each Sum parenthesis. But the result is still the same.

Comment: @Ahmad I never said adding a `distinct=True` works for`Sum`.

Comment: Yeah dear @MosesKoledoye. It seems that it works just with Count.

Comment: Now, what can I do for `Sum` when `distinct=True` does not  work for it?